# Can we replace the sufficient conditions by the new ones in the following theorem?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, functions, derivatives, continuity

Theorem:
Let $I\subset \mathbb R$ be an interval and a function $f:I \to \mathbb R$ be strictly monotone and continuous on $I$.Let $g:=f^{-1}:f(I)\to \mathbb R$.If $f$ is differentiable at $c\in I$ and $f'(c)\neq0$ then $g$ is differentiable at $f(c)$ and $g'(f(c))=\frac{1}{f'(c)}$ .

In this theorem can we replace 'strictly monotone and continuous' by the assumptions that $f$ is 'invertible and continuous' or by 'injective and continuous' or by 'injective and having IVP on $I$'.

I think any of these conditions will act the same i.e. they will all provide me with the facts I need to prove the original version of the theorem.
Another question is how to generalize this theorem for arbitrary domain $X$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As an example I'll consider an invertible and continuous function and will show that it has to be strictly monotonic.

Assume $x<y$ are points in $I$ and, w.l.o.g, let's assume $f(x) < f(y)$. ($f(x)=f(y)$ would contradict the fact that $f$ is invertible).

Now assume $x < r < y$. Claim: $f(x) < f(r) < f(y)$. Assume that this is not true. The $f(x)\ge f(r) $ of $f(r)\ge f(y)$. Since both cases are similar, I'll only look at the first one. $f(x)=f(r)$ is impossible, so $f(x) > f(r) $. But then be the mean value theorem there is $s \in (r,y)$ sucht that $f(s) = f(x)$, contradicting the invertibility of $f$.

Comment: So,as I am saying any of these condition is fine,right?

Comment: @KishalaySarkar yep. But you need to work on connected sets, i.e. intervals.

Comment: And the fact $f'(c)\neq 0$ is essential because we want to avoid the situation of infinite derivative of inverse(although it is a bit informal to say,because we do not consider the differential quotient's infinite limit as a derivative).e.g.$ f(x)=x^3$ with $f^{-1}(x)=x^{\frac{1}{3}}$.

Comment: @KishalaySarkar Right. That condition is, of course, still needed.

Comment: How to generalize this theorem for an arbitrary domain $X$ in place of interval domain $I$.

Comment: @ if you look at the reasoning you'll note that you need the ordering of the real line and an existene theorem like the MVT. While there are some quite sophisticated existence theorems for continuous maps out there for more complicated domains (like higher dimensional discs) the ordering is typically not available. Anyway, there are some interesting theorems, but this is not a topic for a discussion in the comment area of your question. You might consider to look into the realm on nonlinear functional analysis if you have mastered the basic.

Comment: I am talking about $X\subset \mathbb R$.

Comment: @KishalaySarkar As soon as the domain is no longer connected there is no way to make the critical conclusion using the MVT. You can then work only on each connected component indivually.

Comment: Do we require MVT to prove the original version of the theorem,I do not think so,it can be done without MVT(talking of the original version of theorem).